# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (include): include could not find load file: gmxVersionInfo

Tags: c++, cmake

I was trying to install gromacs for which cmake is required. CMake installation have been done and no problem was shown in there. But when I tried to run this command

```
cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON
```

the following error is showing... Please help me to solve this issue...

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTreeInfo


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxVersionInfo


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:65 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTypeReference


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:66 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTypeProfile


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTypeTSAN


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTypeASAN


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTypeMSAN


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:70 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxBuildTypeReleaseWithAssert


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:102 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    gmxCPackUtilities


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:103 (gmx_cpack_init):
  Unknown CMake command "gmx_cpack_init".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/prachi/software/gromacs/gromacs-2016-beta2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Where did you get source code? I've just tried with latest git HEAD and all works fine.

Comment: You are probably missing part of the code. If I recall correctly, there is a flag for the cmake script to download code during the installation.

Comment: @nikaza All those files which produce errors must be in ```<project root>/cmake``` folder as you can see here http://repo.or.cz/gromacs.git/tree/HEAD:/cmake. So nothing to download. Just ```git clone git://git.gromacs.org/gromacs.git; cd gromics; mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON``` will work.

Comment: @SergeiNikulov have followed your instruction ... no error was shown during installation but  "mdrrun -version" is giving "this package is not installed, you can install it by sudo apt-get gromacs " ...

Comment: @user163263 I'm not familiar with gromacs exactly, but perhaps you forget to do ```make install``` after the build, or missed some configuration. Please read official documentation on gromacs site http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Installation_Instructions_4.5

Answer (score 0):

You are not compiling from the location you think you are. Your observations are most consistent with `mkdir build;
cd build;
mkdir build;
cd build;
cmake ..`